# Mainframe programming using DFSORT

Tags: sorting, mainframe, zos, dfsort

I am trying to add a header to a mainframe file and I found this:

```
SORT FIELDS=COPY
OUTFIL REMOVECC,
HEADER1=(1:C'COUNTRY_CODE',13:C',',14:C'CHECK_SEQ_NUMBER',30:C',',
         31:C'FORM_INDICATOR')
OUTREC BUILD=(1:1,2,3:C',',4:4,5,9:C',',10:10,1,80:X)
```

Do I need the 2nd AND 5th row? What will the 5th accomplish?

Sorry I am leaning how to write code for the mainframe.

Comment: What 'Header'? This means nothing on its own. Edit your question and tell us much more about what you are trying to do. Please take the [tour] and learn [ask].

Comment: I have a file out put that i need to add header before converting it to .csv

Comment: the file looks like"

Comment: 210000000  Andres  Gutierrez   123 N street apt. 3      Wichita  KS   100  100  FT  WS

Comment: THE HEADER SHOULD BE  WIN_NBR  FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME  ADDRESS  CHR_STR WRK_LOC  TYPE  CORP

Comment: Please actually read @greg-449's comments. And "Edit your question"

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

The 'CC' in REMOVECC stands for carriage control character. These characters are needed to create printable reports. But if you don't need that character (we mostly don't) then you can suppress them by using REMOVECC. So, you may want to keep the 2nd Line.

HEADER1 builds the header with columns as you mentioned, COUNTRY_CODE etc. This header is Not present in your input dataset, so you are creating this new record in the output dataset.

And, then you are copying your input records to output (after header) via OUTREC. So, you want to keep Line 5 as well.

.

Answer (score 1):

@William Edward Sanchez-Weeks , Also you don't need to do the math by counting the position when you do BUILD with data and header you have. SORT will handle it internally.

Sort card you posted:

```
SORT FIELDS=COPY
OUTFIL REMOVECC,
HEADER1=(1:C'COUNTRY_CODE',13:C',',14:C'CHECK_SEQ_NUMBER',30:C',',
     31:C'FORM_INDICATOR')
OUTREC BUILD=(1:1,2,3:C',',4:4,5,9:C',',10:10,1,80:X)
```

can be written as

```
SORT FIELDS=COPY
OUTFIL REMOVECC,
HEADER1=(C'COUNTRY_CODE',C',',C'CHECK_SEQ_NUMBER',C',',C'FORM_INDICATOR')
OUTREC BUILD=(1,2,C',',4,5,C',',10,1,80:X)
```

Both gives same result.